# mongoose Model is not callable tslint error

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs, tslint

I have a simple nest js service which looks like below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Collection } from './interfaces/collection.interface';
import { CollectionDto } from './dto/collection.dto';
import { COLLECTION } from '../constants';

@Injectable()
export class CollectionsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(COLLECTION) private readonly collectionModel: Model<Collection>
  ) {}

  async getAllCollections(): Promise<Collection[]> {
    const collections = await this.collectionModel.find().exec();
    return collections;
  }

  async addCollection(collectionDto: CollectionDto): Promise<Collection> {
    const newCollection = await this.collectionModel(collectionDto);
    return newCollection.save();
  }
}
```

The code is working well but I am getting tslint warning ts(2348). Does anybody know how to work around it a different way than use `// @ts-ignore` rule?

[image: screenshot that shows what is happening here]

Comment: Press alt+F8 when hovering your cursor over the error should give you the reason

Comment: It's giving me the same info `Value of type 'Model<Collection, {}>' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?ts(2348)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `new` worked for me. This is how I did it. Try it.

`const newCollection = await new this.collectionModel(collectionDto);`

Comment: do you know why it is needed suddenly?

Answer (score 1):

Try return `new newCollection.save();` The schema is a constructor.

This works in Node.js, so it should also work in React if we are both usign Mongoose.

Comment: It's not working for that, why would it work? In my opinion, it's issue of Mongoose @types npm library or ts lint.